# Syntax error MAC El Capitan

Tags: php

I keep getting error on apache.
I upgraded to El Capitan from Mountain Lion

Error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 59 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so, 10): image not found

Comment: See if this is what you looking for? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3705248

Comment: Sounds like apache issue, not PHP.